# How do I mount, edit and repack an .img file?

Tags: 11.10, mount, android

I have downloaded a .img file to use on my Android device.

I have to edit a file in the image in order to use it.

How can I mount the file so I can edit the text file and then re-pack the .img?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the standard o loop mount?

`mount -o loop file.img /mnt/img`

then edit and unmount normally

`umount /mnt/img/`

Comment: I have now, and I get 'mount: you must specify the filesystem type
' in return.

Comment: @Rasmus: it is a partition or disk image? In the second case you need to use an appropriate offset in `-o loop,offset=NUMBER`.

Comment: @Rasmus Since your question seems to be about Android images, it may be a bit more difficult, you you would probably need to unpack and repack the whole image again. http://askubuntu.com/a/129388/40581

Comment: If your image contains multiple partitions, you have to set an offset-value as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/538942).