# How to mount sd-card image created with dd?

Tags: mount, sd-card, dd

I have created an image of my Raspberry Pi SD-card using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf of=/home/myusername/raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img
```

The SD-card includes two partitions (one vfat, one ext4) which are automatically mounted when I plug the card in.

My question: **How can I mount these partitions from the .img file?**

---

More details:

```
$ fdisk -l raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img 

Disk raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img: 3974 MB, 3974103040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 483 cylinders, total 7761920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000981cb

                          Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img2          122880     7761919     3819520   83  Linux
```

Comment: You want to mount the image without writing it to de SD card?

Comment: Yes, I want to have full access to the filesystem stored in the .img file so that I can copy/modify/delete/etc. files without having a SD card

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/reading-a-filesystem-from-a-whole-disk-image) helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, tried both attempts. The first one didn't create the /dev/loop0p1 device. The second one (I have calculated the starting point accordingly) throws a `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error` problem

Comment: In addition, `sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0` claims: Disk /dev/loop0 doesn't contain a valid partition table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After some additonal testing I found the solution myself: `kpartx`

```
sudo kpartx -a raspberry-backup-2014-04-10.img
```

This command created `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` and `/dev/mapper/loop0p2`. Afterwards these partitions can be mounted straight forward:

```
sudo mount -o rw -t ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p2 mount_target/
```

Comment: In ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, partitions in images can be mounted by double-clicking the .img file in the file browser. They are mounted read-only, however, and cannot be remounted writable. When I need to modify the filesystem in an image, kpartx is still the best tool to achieve it.

Answer (score 49):

To avoid the need to create separate images for each partition or installing a utility like `kpartx`, you can mount each partition individually by specifying an `offset` in the `mount` command.

First examine the partitions in the image file and determine the offset by using `fdisk`:

```
$ fdisk -u -l rpi_image280914 

Disk rpi_image280914: 16.0 GB, 16012804096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31275008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cdac7

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
rpi_image280914p1   *        2048      514047      256000    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
rpi_image280914p2          540672    31242239    15350784   83  Linux
```

Take the `Start` sector of the partition you want and multiply that value by the `Units` size. So if you want the second partition you'll get `540672 * 512 = 276824064`.

Now create a folder and mount the partition:

```
mkdir rpi_partition2
sudo mount -o loop,offset=276824064 rpi_image280914 rpi_partition2/
```

Once you are done doing what you want with the partition data:

```
sudo umount rpi_partition2/
rm -r rpi_partition2/
```

Comment: I was not able to mount more than one partition. Would that be because we need to specify the size? (`sizelimit=...` along the `offset=...`) Or is the `loop` device not allowing me to mount more than one partition from a given file?

Answer (score 2):

if your goal is to explore or modify the content of a partition (file system), this command line will mount the file system of the sd card dump **my_sdcard_dump.img** into the directory **mount_dir**.

```
part_id=2; INFILE=my_sdcard_dump.img; MOUNTPT=mount_dir PARTITION=${part_id}; sudo mount "$INFILE" "$MOUNTPT" -o loop,offset=$[ `/sbin/sfdisk -d "$INFILE" | grep "start=" | head -n $PARTITION | tail -n1 | sed 's/.*start=[ ]*//' | sed 's/,.*//'` * 512 ]
```

Comment: Explanation to the subcommands (you can als add this to your answer):This subcommand reads and calculates the offset: `/sbin/sfdisk -d "$INFILE" | grep "start=" | head -n $PARTITION | tail -n1 | sed 's/.*start=[ ]*//' | sed 's/,.*//'`. `sfdisk -d` gives all partition information of your image user readable. `grep "start="` selects all lines that contain a partition start. `head -n $PARTITION | tail -n1` gives the n-th line, which corresponds to the respective selected partition number. I dont know `sed`, but `sed 's/.*start=[ ]*//' | sed 's/,.*//'` returns the offset. `$[... * 512]` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with an image of a whole disk with multiple partitions is [quite tricky](http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux). Linux was not designed to read a partition table out of a regular file, even when attached to a loopback device, so you must carefully identify the offsets of the partitions and pass them in to the `mount` command.

The preferable way would be to create separate images of each partition:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf1 of=/home/myusername/raspberry-backup-sdf1-2014-04-10.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sdf2 of=/home/myusername/raspberry-backup-sdf2-2014-04-10.img
```

Now you can easily treat these files as if they were individual partitions on a disk, mounting them as you normally would a real disk partition, by mapping them to a [loop device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device). A loop device, or loopback device, is a virtual device that provides a translation layer for Linux to treat a file as a block device (like a disk or partition).

The loop devices are typically `/dev/loop0` through `/dev/loop8`. Identify an unused loop device with the `losetup` command:

```
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0
loop: can't get info on device /dev/loop0: No such device or address
```

This response indicates an unassigned loop device. Now we can assign the loop device to one of our image files:

```
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /home/myusername/raspberry-backup-sdf1-2014-04-10.img
```

Absence of output from this command indicates success. Now `/dev/loop0` is for most purposes functionally equivalent to `/dev/sdf1` of your SD card, and you can mount it as you normally would:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/loop0 /media/sdimage-1
```

Repeat the process using another loop device to mount the other partition. When you're done, unmount the filesystems and unassign the loop devices:

```
sudo umount /dev/loop0
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: I would like to avoid creating two image files, because - among other minor reasons - I would like to distribute the image to other people so that they can use it to initialize their SD-cards with. Therefore, the different partitions like /boot etc. have to be in one file.